# Does next-auth use JWT or sessions and where are they stored?

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I completely don't understand the next-auth documentation.

I understand you can use both JWT and sessions, but how do you tell next-auth which one you're using?
And where does next-auth store its sessions or JWTs? On the server or client-side?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NextAuth.js uses a JWT to save the user's session by default, when a database adapter is not used.

> NextAuth.js by default uses JSON Web Tokens for saving the user's
> session. However, if you use a [database adapter](https://next-auth.js.org/adapters/overview), the database will be
> used to persist the user's session. You can force the usage of JWT
> when using a database [through the configuration options](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/options#session). Since v4 all
> our JWT tokens are now encrypted by default with A256GCM.

The JWT is stored in an `httpOnly` cookie, not accessible on the client-side.

> You can use JWT to securely store information you do not mind the
> client knowing even without encryption, as the JWT is stored in a
> server-readable-only cookie so data in the JWT is not accessible to
> third party JavaScript running on your site.

This is documented in NextAuth.js [JSON Web Tokens FAQ section](https://next-auth.js.org/faq#json-web-tokens).